# Точки монтирования Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Суть в чем: у меня есть ssd на 256гб и HDD на 1тб. Я планирую при установке ubuntu смонтировать на корень `/` ssd, а на `/home` hdd. Ну типа логично, система и приложения будут установлены на ssd а весь мусор пусть лежит на hdd.

Потом я так подумал, есть же еще `/tmp` и возможно еще какие папки куда можно будет раскидать места с hdd? Как бы сделали вы?

Comment: Я бы не переусложнял, звучит нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Потом я так подумал, есть же еще /tmp и возможно еще какие папки куда
> можно будет раскидать места с hdd? Как бы сделали вы?

сейчас `/tmp` у большинства дистрибутивов автоматом *монтируется в ОЗУ*, что правильно с точки зрения использования избыточной памяти. Да и другие *системные папки* без большой необходимости и главное понимания для чего, не стоит трогать.

> Суть в чем: у меня есть ssd на 256гб и HDD на 1тб. Я планирую при
> установке ubuntu смонтировать на корень / ssd, а на /home hdd. Ну типа
> логично, система и приложения будут установлены на ssd а весь мусор
> пусть лежит на hdd.

обычно хомяк(`/home`) лучше держать на `ssd` что позволит ускорить загрузку программ так как пользовательские конфиги также хранятся в хомяке и стартовать с `ssd` они будут быстрее чем с `hdd`. Сам `hdd` после установки можно просто смонтировать в одну из папок в хомяке, например в `/home/$USER/mnt/hdd`, естественно предварительно её создав и прописав в `/etc/fstab`, куда уже в последствии скидывать *тяжелые* файлы(фильмы, музыка, игры ...). Другой вопрос делать хомяк отдельным разделом или оставить в корне. Если планируется к установке тока одна система на данный `ssd` то городить лишние разделы а потом парится с их размерами, как по мне, смысла нету, и проще оставить хомяк в корне, даже если будет нужна переустановка системы то перенос хомячных файлов(в том числе и конфигов) это не является проблемой при наличии какого-либо live USB дистрибутива в том числе установочного.

Comment: Ну я так понимаю, допустим, я захотел себе поставить apache и phpstorm. Вот он мне apache положит в /var, а storm в /opt и оно так и будет раскладываться по корню. А вот я скачал фильм и он ляжет в home. То есть это удобно, но ты наверно подчеркнул тут такой важный момент, что, допустим я установил гит, он упал в /opt, а конфиг лежит в /home на hdd? И вот он начнет постоянно этот конфиг с hdd читать при работе с гит, что в свою очередь нивелирует расположение самой программы на ssd? Правильно я понял?

Comment: Теперь вопрос второй не менее важный, я смонтировал /home/$USER/hdd и теперь ($USER - это вот так и писать? это потом подставиться на место текущего созданного пользователя?) мне придется вручную постоянно делать перенос мусора с /home в эту директорию? Ну то есть банально тяжелые файлы туда кидать?

Comment: `что в свою очередь нивелирует расположение самой программы на ssd?` - одно другому не мешает, а дополняет, грубо говоря, у вас есть некая пользовательская программа, обычно исполняемый код лежит в `/usr/bin`, используемые ею библиотеки в `/usr/lib`, разные ресурсы программы в `/usr/share`, основные конфиги в `/etc`, возможно что-то еще, далее при 1запуске от пользователя основной конфиг зачастую дублируется в `/home/$USER/.config` автоматом и/или самим пользователем или когда пользователь меняет какие-либо настройки в программе, то есть загрузка будет идти по цепочке `bin-lib-shаre-.config`

Comment: если конфиг будет лежать на hdd то естественно это немного увеличит время запуска самой программы. И да, забыл еще, во время работы программы она может генерировать некоторые данные для своей работы и которые сохраняются при её закрытии а при следующем запуске вновь подтягиваются из `/home/$USER/.cache`, то есть цепочка может растянутся до `bin-lib-shаre-.config-.cache` и в отличии от того-же конфига кэш программы может быть довольно большим особенно если брать те-же браузеры

Comment: `$USER - это вот так и писать?` - нет, вместо этого указываете имя пользователя, это просто для наглядности, по сути `$USER` это переменная которая выводит(`echo $USER`) имя пользователя в терминале, часто используется в скриптах так же как например и переменная `$HOME` обычно эквивалентная `/home/$USER`

Comment: `мне придется вручную постоянно делать перенос мусора с /home в эту директорию? Ну то есть банально тяжелые файлы туда кидать?` - зачем ? вы сразу же и ложите эти файлы куда нужно по месту в смонтированную папку, для системы это будет всё прозрачно, просто папка у пользователя у которой будет соответствующий размер. Можно даже вообще не парится указав в настройках соответствующих программ, тех же торрентов, браузеров и тому подобное место куда сохранять скачанные файлы.